# Delete rows from table after certain time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to delete rows from table.

```
Create Table #Test (id int, name varchar(25), crdate datetime2)
insert into #Test values (1,'sam' , '2018-12-31 16:44:51.000')
insert into #Test values (2,'ram' , '2018-07-15 16:44:51.000') 
insert into #Test values (3,'pam' , '2018-08-31 16:44:51.000')
insert into #Test values (4,'kam' , '2019-01-31 16:44:51.000')
insert into #Test values (5,'tam' , '2017-07-01 16:44:51.000')
Select * From #Test
```

I need to delete those records from the table where `crdate <= current year minus one year`, and using first day of first month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM #Test 
WHERE crdate <= DATEADD(D,-DAY(DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) - 1), DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()))
```

**Explanation**

```
-- Subtract the number of days from the current month, add add it to the previous year
DATEADD(D, -DAY(
               -- Get number of days of current month (from previous year) to subtract  ( -1 to leave 1 day)
               DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) - 1), 
  -- Get the today's equivalent date from last year
  DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) 
)
```